# Bitwise operators: How to check if source port is great than 32767 (0x7FFF)

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I have a program that reads a binary file of 20 bytes, modifies the data and then write on another binary file. I am trying to check if the source port is bigger than 32767  or(0x7FFF).
If it is bigger then I must zero out the most significant two bits of it. I am only allowed to use bitwise operators. Anybody has any idea how could I do it? Thanks.

```
Data: 32 27 A9 49 03 8C BD 89 01 87 9B 8D 50 13 00 00 FF FF 00 00
Source port: 32 27 (16 bits)

void modify(const unsigned char oldData [], unsigned char newData []){

/*Accessing the souce port oldData[0] and oldData[1].*/


}
```

Comment: If a 16 bit value is greater than `0x7FFF`, then the most significant bit is necessarily set. This is equivalent to how if a four digit decimal number is greater than 999, then the most significant digit (thousands-place) is necessarily non-zero.

Comment: @thatotherguy: Indeed, if and only if.

Comment: @thatotherguy is not the 16 bit, but the hexadecimal value 3227.

Comment: @thatotherguy the value of the source port is: 3227

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Your paste says the source port is two bytes. That means the value is 16 bits long, even if the leading bits are zero. If it has the hexadecimal value 0x3237, then in binary it's `0011001000110111`. The first bit is 0, which means that the value is less than or equal to 0x7FFF.

Comment: @thatotherguy yes, but what if the value is bigger than 0x7FFF? That's what I need to check for. I can't assume the value will always be 3237

Comment: `if (port >> 15) { /* then it is larger than 0x7fff */ }`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I will try that!

Comment: `if (port & ~0x...00007FFF > 0) { /* the same idea */ }`, but you almost had the idea. Think about it this way: `32767` == 0x`7FFF` == 0b`0111111111111111`. Now, for _any_ number greater than that number, what would be the case for the most significant (on the left) bit?. How about `32768` == 0x`8000` == 0b`1000000000000000`. Keep in mind this changes slightly if you consider a number larger than 16 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pick out the port value from the data. This depends on endianness. little or big.

You will need to know how your data is organized - if the 32 is the high or low part.

Assuming your data is little-endian, you can read it like this:

```
#include <endian.h>

void modify()
{
    uint16_t port = le16toh( *((uint16_t*)oldData) );
    if(port>32767)
        {/*whatever*/}
```

For the particular case of checking against >=32768 , which is >=0x8000, can test the high-bit as already commented:

```
if(oldData[1]&0x80) // [1] is highbyte if using little-endian data.
    {/*whatever*/}
```